# "It was not" or "it wasn't"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, word-order

I've been reading a novel which original language is chinese and in the translation a there's a part that I don't know if its the correct:

> *[...] "This butterfly was extremely intelligent. **Not only was it not frightened**, it even temporarily stopped on his fingertips, both wings glittering and beautiful to the utmost degree."*

which one is correct, ***"was it not"*** or ***"it wasn't"*** ?

I'm not a native speaker, and since the amount of time given in the schools to english subject is very little so I've learn english mostly by my own, therefore I apologize and I would like to know if I made any mistake in here, thank you.

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as 
the definition/explanation and examples /
grammar rules and examples 
in a dictionary or other trusted reference. For example [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/)

Comment: It should be **Not only was it frightened**. The second *not* seems to be a typo.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - you are mistaken. The butterfly was not frightened, as the text makes clear (it stepped on his fingertips). No typo. No mistake.

Comment: Ah.. I didn't read the full sentence. Only read emboldened text.. my apologies.